# Grouping an array at three levels using reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping, reduce

I want to group this array at three levels, `id`, `entryId` and `memberId`.
This is one of many things I've tried so far & nearly does what I want. However I can't understand how to populate the members array with the 'rest' using key2.
I'm very new to all of this but trying to understand exactly what is happening.
Any help would be vary gratefully received.

```js
const matches = [{
    entryId: 58,
    firstName: "K",
    id: 37,
    lastName: "Birch",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-10-12T07:25:08.000Z",
    memberId: 9,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 7,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Caroline Hogg",
    resultId: 123,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  },
  {
    entryId: 58,
    firstName: "J",
    id: 37,
    lastName: "Thorn",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-10-12T07:25:08.000Z",
    memberId: 17,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 7,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Caroline Hogg",
    resultId: 123,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  },
  {
    entryId: 59,
    firstName: "G",
    id: 37,
    lastName: "Sand",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-10-12T07:25:08.000Z",
    memberId: 60,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 4,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Caroline Hogg",
    resultId: 124,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  },
  {
    entryId: 59,
    firstName: "C",
    id: 37,
    lastName: "Hogg",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-10-12T07:25:08.000Z",
    memberId: 4,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 4,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Caroline Hogg",
    resultId: 124,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  },
  {
    entryId: 58,
    firstName: "K",
    id: 38,
    lastName: "Birch",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-09-27T16:53:40.000Z",
    memberId: 9,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 7,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Liz Grid",
    resultId: 122,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  },
  {
    entryId: 58,
    firstName: "J",
    id: 38,
    lastName: "Thorn",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-09-27T16:53:40.000Z",
    memberId: 17,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 7,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Liz Grid",
    resultId: 122,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  },
  {
    entryId: 60,
    firstName: "K",
    id: 38,
    lastName: "Batty",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-09-27T16:53:40.000Z",
    memberId: 14,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 9,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Liz Grid",
    resultId: 127,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  },
  {
    entryId: 60,
    firstName: "K",
    id: 38,
    lastName: "Rafe",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-09-27T16:53:40.000Z",
    memberId: 6,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 9,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Liz Grid",
    resultId: 127,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  },
  {
    entryId: 59,
    firstName: "C",
    id: 39,
    lastName: "Hogg",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-10-12T07:23:27.000Z",
    memberId: 4,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 4,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Caroline Hogg",
    resultId: 125,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  },
  {
    entryId: 59,
    firstName: "G",
    id: 39,
    lastName: "Sand",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-10-12T07:23:27.000Z",
    memberId: 60,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 4,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Caroline Hogg",
    resultId: 125,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  },
  {
    entryId: 60,
    firstName: "K",
    id: 39,
    lastName: "Rafe",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-10-12T07:23:27.000Z",
    memberId: 6,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 9,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Caroline Hogg",
    resultId: 126,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  },
  {
    entryId: 60,
    firstName: "K",
    id: 39,
    lastName: "Batty",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-10-12T07:23:27.000Z",
    memberId: 14,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 9,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Caroline Hogg",
    resultId: 126,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  }
];

const grouped = matches.reduce(
  (
    r, {
      id,
      played,
      matchDate,
      resultEnteredBy,
      roundLeagueBoxId,
      leagueId,
      entryId,
      registerId,
      resultId,
      set1,
      set2,
      tb,
      retired,
      walkover,
      points,
      result,
      ...rest
    }
  ) => {
    const key = `${id}`;
    const key2 = `${entryId}`;
    r[key] = r[key] || {
      id,
      played,
      matchDate,
      resultEnteredBy,
      roundLeagueBoxId,
      leagueId,
      Entries: [],
    };
    r[key]["Entries"].push({
      entryId,
      registerId,
      resultId,
      set1,
      set2,
      tb,
      retired,
      walkover,
      points,
      result,
      Members: [],
    });

    return r;
  }, {});
  
  console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can you please provide an expected output as it is - at least to me - not very clear what you mean by grouping at three levels? Should `id`, `entryId` and `memberId` be use similar to a composite key in databases, or do you want some nested reducing?

Comment: "*I want to group this array at three levels, `id`, `entryId` and `memberId`*" okay, what does that mean? What (exact) result(s) do you want? "*This is one of many things I've tried so far & nearly does what I want.*" - so, how does it fail, what exactly is wrong with the result?

Comment: Seems like to populate the `Members` array, you need to find the corresponding `Entries` array element first & then simply do another push.

Answer (score 0):

This answer extends the code given in the question in order to add data / object into the `"Members"` array.

```js
const myGroupBy = matches => {
  return matches.reduce(
  (
    r, {
      id,
      played,
      matchDate,
      resultEnteredBy,
      roundLeagueBoxId,
      leagueId,
      entryId,
      registerId,
      resultId,
      set1,
      set2,
      tb,
      retired,
      walkover,
      points,
      result,
      memberId,     // de-structure to directly access
      firstName,    // "memberId", "firstName", "lastName" props
      lastName,
      ...rest
    }
  ) => {
    const key = `${id}`;
    const key2 = `${entryId}`;
    r[key] = r[key] || {
      id,
      played,
      matchDate,
      resultEnteredBy,
      roundLeagueBoxId,
      leagueId,
      Entries: [],
    };
    r[key]["Entries"].push({
      entryId,
      registerId,
      resultId,
      set1,
      set2,
      tb,
      retired,
      walkover,
      points,
      result,
      Members: [],
    });
    
    // find "entries" array index that matches
    // "entryId" of current iteration
    const entryIdx = r[key].Entries
      .findIndex(
        iterEntry => iterEntry.entryId === entryId
      );
    
    // push to "Members" array of the corresponding
    // "entries" array element
    r[key].Entries[entryIdx].Members.push({
      memberId, firstName, lastName
    });
    
    return r;
  }, {});
};

const matches = [{
    entryId: 58,
    firstName: "K",
    id: 37,
    lastName: "Birch",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-10-12T07:25:08.000Z",
    memberId: 9,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 7,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Caroline Hogg",
    resultId: 123,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  },
  {
    entryId: 58,
    firstName: "J",
    id: 37,
    lastName: "Thorn",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-10-12T07:25:08.000Z",
    memberId: 17,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 7,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Caroline Hogg",
    resultId: 123,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  },
  {
    entryId: 59,
    firstName: "G",
    id: 37,
    lastName: "Sand",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-10-12T07:25:08.000Z",
    memberId: 60,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 4,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Caroline Hogg",
    resultId: 124,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  },
  {
    entryId: 59,
    firstName: "C",
    id: 37,
    lastName: "Hogg",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-10-12T07:25:08.000Z",
    memberId: 4,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 4,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Caroline Hogg",
    resultId: 124,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  },
  {
    entryId: 58,
    firstName: "K",
    id: 38,
    lastName: "Birch",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-09-27T16:53:40.000Z",
    memberId: 9,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 7,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Liz Grid",
    resultId: 122,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  },
  {
    entryId: 58,
    firstName: "J",
    id: 38,
    lastName: "Thorn",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-09-27T16:53:40.000Z",
    memberId: 17,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 7,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Liz Grid",
    resultId: 122,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  },
  {
    entryId: 60,
    firstName: "K",
    id: 38,
    lastName: "Batty",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-09-27T16:53:40.000Z",
    memberId: 14,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 9,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Liz Grid",
    resultId: 127,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  },
  {
    entryId: 60,
    firstName: "K",
    id: 38,
    lastName: "Rafe",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-09-27T16:53:40.000Z",
    memberId: 6,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 9,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Liz Grid",
    resultId: 127,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  },
  {
    entryId: 59,
    firstName: "C",
    id: 39,
    lastName: "Hogg",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-10-12T07:23:27.000Z",
    memberId: 4,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 4,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Caroline Hogg",
    resultId: 125,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  },
  {
    entryId: 59,
    firstName: "G",
    id: 39,
    lastName: "Sand",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-10-12T07:23:27.000Z",
    memberId: 60,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 4,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Caroline Hogg",
    resultId: 125,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  },
  {
    entryId: 60,
    firstName: "K",
    id: 39,
    lastName: "Rafe",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-10-12T07:23:27.000Z",
    memberId: 6,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 9,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Caroline Hogg",
    resultId: 126,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  },
  {
    entryId: 60,
    firstName: "K",
    id: 39,
    lastName: "Batty",
    leagueId: 3,
    matchDate: "2019-10-12T07:23:27.000Z",
    memberId: 14,
    played: 3,
    points: 0,
    registerId: 9,
    result: null,
    resultEnteredBy: "Caroline Hogg",
    resultId: 126,
    retired: 0,
    roundLeagueBoxId: 19,
    set1: 0,
    set2: 0,
    tb: 0,
    walkover: null,
  }
];

console.log(myGroupBy(matches));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with finding the entry index. I've now changed the grouping using your logic. This is now exactly how i want it.

Answer (score 0):

```
const grouped = results.reduce(
    (
      r,
      {
        id,
        played,
        matchDate,
        resultEnteredBy,
        roundLeagueBoxId,
        leagueId,
        entryId,
        registerId,
        resultId,
        set1,
        set2,
        tb,
        retired,
        walkover,
        points,
        result,
        memberId,
        firstName,
        lastName,
      }
    ) => {
      const key = `${id}`;
      const fullName = `${firstName[0]} ${lastName}`;

      r[key] = r[key] || {
        Matches: [],
      };

      if (!r[key].Matches.find((other) => id === other.id)) {
        r[key].Matches.push({
          id,
          played,
          matchDate,
          resultEnteredBy,
          roundLeagueBoxId,
          leagueId,
          Entries: [],
        });
      }

      if (
        !r[key].Matches[0].Entries.find((other) => entryId === other.entryId)
      ) {
        r[key].Matches[0].Entries.push({
          entryId,
          registerId,
          resultId,
          set1,
          set2,
          tb,
          retired,
          walkover,
          points,
          result,
          Members: [],
        });
      }

      const entryIdx = r[key].Matches[0].Entries.findIndex(
        (iterEntry) => iterEntry.entryId === entryId
      );

      r[key].Matches[0].Entries[entryIdx].Members.push({
        memberId,
        fullName,
      });

      return r;
    },
    {}
);
```

Thank you for the help.